# Filter lines according to word by powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to filter lines according to specific word from file in powershell.

For example: the files `animal1.txt` and `animal2.txt`. Every file contain lines

```
dog
cat
dog
dog
bird
```

Then I want to create two derived files:
`animal1_bak.txt` that stores lines which contains the word 'dog' from `animal1.txt`

`animal2_bak.txt` that stores lines which contains the word 'dog' from `animal2.txt`

What I found on web is:

```
Select-String -Path "*.*" -Pattern "dog"
```

But the instruction to create the derived word is missing.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can first get-content and use set-content like below

```
Get-Content -Path E:\KTDocs\Scripts\animal1.txt |  where {
 $_ -like  '*dog*'} |Set-Content e:\animalbak.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
select-string -Path "c:\temp\animal*.txt" -Pattern "dog" | Group Path | %{
$FileName="{0}_bak.txt" -f $_.Name
$_.Group.Line | select -unique  | Out-File $FileName -Append 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$folderpath = "D:\AnimalFolder" # your folder path here
$Allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Recurse -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |where{$_.Name -match ".txt"} |Select-Object -expandproperty FullName
foreach($filepath in $allfiles)
{
    $Data = get-content $filepath
    foreach($line in $data)
    {
        if($line -match "dog")
        {
            $newpath = $filepath.split('.')[0]
            $getfullpath = $newpath + "_bak.txt"
            $line | out-file $getfullpath -append
        }
    }
}
```